# HTML not loading Javascript/css file

Tags: javascript, html

There are some `js` and `css` file that need to be loaded in my html, but in android webview only `html` is loadin, `js` and `css` are not loadin. Even the `http` request is not sent.

The weird thing is some times it is working as expected.
[links-screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlLX4.png)

Sorry for my bad English, and thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this on a website that uses https, you don't need to specify the protocol again when importing scripts: `src=https://www...` to `src=//www...`

Comment: The request protocol of html is different from that of js.
Is there any difference between these two methods?

Comment: I've encountered instances when scripts where getting "imported sometimes" too, this usually fixed it.

Comment: thanks for answer, i will try it. The headache is that I can't reproduce it now...

Answer (score -1):

The keyword `defer` helps the browser to render JavaScript files once html and css is loaded. Add the keyword `defer` like this:

```
<script src="app.js" defer></defer>
```